# Change of generators and shortest product in groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

Let $G$ be a finitely generated group.

For a set of generators $B$ of $G$, $\ell_B(x)$ is the length of the smallest sequence of elements(and inverse of the elements) in $B$, such that the product equals $x$. $\ell_B(X) = \sum_{x\in X} \ell_B(x)$.

We want to find some function $f$, such that any set of generators $B'$ and $b\in B$, we have $\ell_{B'}(b)\leq f(\ell_B(B'))$.

For example, if $G=\mathbb{Z}$, $B=\{1\}$, then we have
$$ \ell_{B'}(1)\leq \ell_B(B') $$

Indeed, we can pick two relatively prime elements $u,v\in B'$, and solve for $au+bv = 1$ while minimizing $|a|+|b|$. By Bézout's lemma, this can be bounded by $|u|+|v|\leq \ell_B(B')$.

In particular, I would like to see a result like this for $B=\{a,b\}$ and $G$ is the free group generated by $B$.

Comment: Can you ask a more specific question?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I'm interested in techniques or references that solve this kind of problems. Seeing an example for the free group of rank $2$ is good enough.

Comment: In the case of the free group in $B=\{a,b\}$, isn't $\ell_{B'}(x) \le \max\{\ell_{B'}(a),\ell_{B'}(b)\} \ell_B(x)$ an answer?

Comment: @FelipeVoloch that's true, we only need bound on $\ell_{B'}(b)$ for all $b\in B$. I see why I wasn't being clear. I have modified the question.

Comment: Both Profs Leininger and Kapovich in the math dept at UIUC are experts on free-group automorphisms, and could certainly help you with this question.

Comment: Anyway, such a bound should exist in $F_2=\langle a,b\rangle$ for the special reason that all automorphisms are geometric, and asymptotically stretch length roughly as much as their inverses.  This property fails in $F_n$ for $n>2$, so I think no such bound exists in that setting.

Comment: On reflection, the bound might also fail in $F_2$.  What I'm trying to say is that if $\phi$ is the free-group automorphism that sends $B$ to $B'$, then it is true that $\phi^n(w)$ is roughly the same length as $\phi^{-n}(w)$ for all $w$, as $n\to\infty$, but you're interested in what happens for $n=1$, so the rate of convergences is also important.